# Webpack 5 SplitChunksPlugin not generating chunk files

Tags: typescript, webpack, chunks

I am currently updating an Angular 2 project written in Typescript with ES5 and Webpack 1 to utilize Webpack 5.

To solve problems with cachebusting, in the original instance the project has a `webpack.config` shown below to generate a `json` file that would detail the filenames of the created hashed chunks.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./app/client/client-app.ts",
        vendor: './app/client/client-vendor.ts',
        polyfills: './app/client/client-polyfills.ts'
    },
    output: {
        filename: "./app/libs/scripts/[name]-client.[chunkhash].js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),
        new AssetsPlugin({
            filename: 'webpack.assets.client.json',
            path: './app/libs/scripts',
            prettyPrint: true
        }),
    ]
}
```

With the generated file looking like this..

```
{
  "app": {
    "js": "./app/libs/scripts/app-client.94fb68d639f7fe8ce258.js"
  },
  "polyfills": {
    "js": "./app/libs/scripts/polyfills-client.970ace7dddd5f34afb5b.js"
  },
  "vendor": {
    "js": "./app/libs/scripts/vendor-client.18346595f0e2d641067c.js"
  }
}
```

and the folder of files looking like this.
[image]

In the latest version of Webpack 5 it is stated in the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunkscachegroups) the `CommonsChunkPlugin` has been removed in favor of `SplitChunksPlugin`. However when I make adjustments as seen below, the json file is **still** created successfully but all the accompanying `js` files never make their way into the assigned repository, despite no errors appearing in my `cmd` window. Is there something I am misunderstanding here?

```
const AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');

var assetsPlugin = new AssetsPlugin({
    filename: 'webpack-assets.client.json',
    path: './app/libs/scripts',
    prettyPrint: true,
    removeFullPathAutoPrefix: true,
    includeFilesWithoutChunk: true
});

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './app/app.ts',
        polyfills: './app/polyfills.ts',
        vendor: './app/vendor.ts',
    },
    target: 'node',
    output: {
        filename: './app/libs/scripts/[name]-client.[chunkhash].js',
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                default: false,
                vendors: false,

                vendor: {
                    chunks: 'all',
                    test: /client-vendor.ts/
                }
            }
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'ts-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    mode: 'development',
    resolve: {
        "fallback": {
            "timers": require.resolve("timers-browserify")
        }
    },
    plugins: [assetsPlugin]
}
```

[image]

Newly generated json file.

```
{
  "app": {
    "js": "./app/libs/scripts/app-client.c8345edfa6da5d2ad827.js"
  },
  "polyfills": {
    "js": "./app/libs/scripts/polyfills-client.fc21049a83789be81a52.js"
  },
  "vendor": {
    "js": "./app/libs/scripts/vendor-client.d8b3a7d7af94ea7370c4.js"
  }
}
```

Newly generated folder, lacking `js` files..

[image]